# Placing a GA Event Tracking code for a button click

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to place an event tracking code, and for the life of me it will not work. I've done it on other sites and it works without any problems. Not sure if it's because the button code is different. Below is the button code and I've bolded where I placed the event tracking code. Please tell me where I've gone wrong!

```
<div id="optin">

  <form action="http://iuzeit.us7.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=89560f169a7c1aa335b0885ff&amp;id=16962f2a89" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

  <p>iuzeit will be ready for beta testing soon. Leave us your email address and we'll give you exclusive access!</p>

    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>

    <div class="clear" style="padding-top:10px;">
      <center>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" **onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Register for Beta', 'Subscribe', 'Register on Blog Sidebar']);"** name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </center>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an onsubmit on the form tag, instead of onclick on the input tag. The reason being is that event will only fire if the form is submitted and not every time the button is clicked.

Your form tag would look like this:

```
<form action="http://iuzeit.us7.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=89560f169a7c1aa335b0885ff&amp;id=16962f2a89" method="post" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Register for Beta', 'Subscribe', 'Register on Blog Sidebar']);" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
```